# Python: detecting install location of python tools

Tags: python

Python's installation comes with some handy tools, located under 
$YOUR_PYTHON/Tools/Scripts. Is there a platform-independent way to find out where on a system they are located? I want to use ftpmirror.py as part of a shell script.

Comment: N.B. On Fedora there is a separate package named `python-tools` which might not be installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are talking about the source bundle of Python, which includes `Tools/Scripts`, a set of helpful scripts for working with Python Source. It should be noted that they are not a part of Python Standard Library and installers are not obliged to bundle them with their distribution, for e.g in Ubuntu, I don't find it in /usr/lib/python2.6 or some other path.

If you want to rely on any of the `Tools/Scripts`, just carry them along with your script, that would be most portable.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that since the Windows installer includes it, others also do.

Comment: FYI, as of the upcoming Python 3.2 release, the Mac OS X installers will install the `Tools` directory under `/Applications/Python 3.2/Extras`.  That's where the `Demo` directory used to be; it has been removed with the most useful demos updated and placed under `Tools` for Python 3.2.